# Getting successful result with $.ajax request but Error-500 with $http request

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, ajax-request

I am working on a small web application which simplifies the process of creating and populating USPTO IDS forms by accessing data from another server. For accessing data I am using this API - http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/US9623902/biblio.js.

I am doing this with angular and hence I used ***$http*** but it is throwing *error 500 (Internal Server Error)*. while doing it with ***ajax-request***, its working fine. In fact any other method like ***$.get()*** instead of ajax throwing the same error, even I used ***ng-resource get*** method but no help. I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Here are my codes -

```
$.get( "http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/US9623902/biblio.js",
function( data ) {
    vm.inventors = data['ops:world-patent-data']['exchange-documents']['exchange-document']['bibliographic-data']['parties']['inventors']['inventor'];
    console.log(vm.inventors);
});


var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/US9623902/full-cycle.js',
   };
$http(req).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Both of these codes are throwing error 500. Here is the image

[image]

while this code is working fine. But here I am getting an issue of page load, the page is loaded before data is bound to *$scope* and hence not showing on the page.

```
  $.ajax({
     url: 'http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/' + 'US9623902' + '/biblio.js',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: "jsonP",
     success: function(data) {
         vm.inventors = data['ops:world-patent-data']['exchange-documents']['exchange-document']['bibliographic-data']['parties']['inventors']['inventor'];
         console.log(vm.inventors);
     },
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        vm.errorContent = [{
            heading: "Error",
            description: "Could not load json data "
        }];
        return false;
    }
});
```

Image of successful result

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Compare the headers of the requests sent. You can do that from the network tab in Chrome

Comment: I have compared it, both are sending same headers. I used postman, and there I am getting JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get where the problem lies in my **"GET"** request. But **"jsonP"** method of *$http* did solve this issue.

@Sachila - As data is not being sent, the transformation is not required.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `x-www-form-urlencoded` as header, you might need to transform your request.

```
var req = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/US9623902/full-cycle.js',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },

  transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
};
```

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get what this transformRequest is doing. I would be thankful if you could put some more light into it. By the way, i tried your code but no help.

Comment: even if you put the `application/x-www-form-urlencode` header., data pass to the server in json format. so to prevent thet we serialize the json onto string through `transformRequest`

Comment: what if I use application/json there. And when I am checking this in postman, no headers are required to send. it is giving data by simple http get request.